# Hibernate: How to test a JPA/Hibernate Predicate instance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

Having written a Builder class which generates an instance of `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` (using `CriteriaBuilder`) based on conditions, I would like to write a JUnit Test for this class...

However, I do NOT need to test the query itself (for this we do have integration tests) but what I want is testing the `Predicate` instance generated by the Builder.

I'm looking for hints how I can ideally test a `Predicate` instance without digging through the whole API since I did not found a toString method. That would have been the easiest way. ;-)

Assuming it would be just a method generating a `Predicate`, for example:

```
public Predicate createPredicate(CriteriaBuilder b, Root<Cat> c, String searchTerm) {

   Predicate predicate = b.like(c.get("name"), searchTerm + "%");
   predicate = b.and(predicate, b.like(c.get("color"), "%" + searchTerm + "%");

   Predicate subPredicate = b.equal(c.get("id"), searchTerm);
   subPredicate = b.or(subPredicate, b.equal(c.get("alternativeId"), searchTerm);

   predicate = b.and(predicate, subPredicate);

   return predicate;

}
```

Of course this example does not make sense... but it's just as an example. What is the best practice to test the return value?

Actually the output of the Predicate should be something like:

```
name LIKE 'xyz%' 
AND color LIKE '%xyz%'
AND (id = 'xyz' OR alternative_id = 'xyz')
```

I would like to test this output somehow. Of course I could go recursively through the `Predicate` instance but I was hoping to avoid that.

Note: The method is using `Predicate`, `CriteriaBuilder` and `Root` of Hibernate. These are no custom implementations.

Comment: can you please post an example of the same? Means what and how "Predicate instance" is generate by the builder class, not in detail code may be but just in a generic way to understand what you are doing and what you want.

Comment: I used predicate to generate native queries (without criteria builder), I never created any junit test case for it but I created predicate by reading this http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/04/04/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/. May be it will help you

Comment: Thanks Amogh but I'm using `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into `org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler` which generates the correct JPQL for a criteria query.

A compiler for a single predicate without a query makes no sense, because it needs to identify the correct entity variable - your examples need to look like:

```
cat1.name LIKE 'xyz%' 
AND cat1.color LIKE '%xyz%'
AND (cat1.id = 'xyz' OR cat1.alternative_id = 'xyz')
```

And to identify `cat1` the whole query has to be taken into account.

But you could create your own `CriteriaQueryBuilder.RenderingContext` and call `((Renderable) predicate).render(renderingContext);` - that should offer you what you want (or at least the snippet that I just wrote).

Comment: To be honest I haven't found the time to implement the JUnit tests. :-/ However, your answer gives a good idea how to implement my tests and I'm gonna use your idea later. Thank you!